# angular mvp, passing an elementref to a presenter

Tags: angular, mvp

Attempting to implement a *presenter* that is hopefully loosely aware of a `<ng-template #templateRef >` template reference from the *view/component*. An example of the mvp can be found [here](https://github.com/LayZeeDK/ngx-tour-of-heroes-mvp)

I have been having difficulty finding a good way to pass the ElementRef. I am attempting to assign the value to a presenter value in `ngAfterViewInit() { this.presenter.elementRef = this.elementRef }` using `@ViewChild`, but it does not work as its returning `undefined`.

Is there a good way to reference a template from a presenter (better if loosely coupled ...
looked at Renderer2 but figured this wont work)

**Edit:**

I got it to work by calling a function that sets the values on `ngAfterViewInit()` in the component as opposed to a direct setter (the DI of the presenter in the component ctor likely caused the issues), but still think this approach could be improved and loosely coupled -- any thoughts?

**Edit 2:**

Another option is to remove the need for a template ref entirely by SoC of the two template refs into their own components that are linked by the container

Thanks